# How to push to azure app service from a branch other than master?

Tags: git, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I'm deploying my NodeJS app to azure app service (B1) using local git repository, how do I push from a branch other than master?

Comment: I've never used Azure, but if you are deploying to a server in the cloud, you should install `git` like any other computer and bring the repo to the machine. And if you need to switch between branches `git checkout <branch_name>`

Answer (score 10):

You could use `git push azure <branch-name>:master`. If you've already checkout on the branch you want to push, use `git push azure HEAD:master`. This command will push your current working commit to Azure.

`git push aaa xxx:yyy` means push local branch `xxx` to remote repository `aaa`'s `yyy` branch.

Answer (score 3):

When you set up continuous deployment using git, you can specify the branch to deploy from:

[image]

Here is a walk through: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment

Comment: this method worked for me :- 

`git push azure <branch-name>:master`

Do you have an explanation what does this do?